# Keyboard shortcut to insert text - Keynote

Tags: keyboard, keynote, shortcut, text-input

I'm new to Keynote and am disappointed by the lack of shortcuts for basic actions like "insert text". Any idea of how to attribute a single key such as the letter "T" to insert text action?

If for any reason a single letter without cmd/opt/whatever modifier key is not recommended, I'm happy with other possibilities..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding keyboard shortcuts through System Preferences? See [this article](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18418) on the Apple Knowledge Base.

Comment: I thought I did but I did not quite get correctly how to invoke the command I guess ! No I got this alright, although it seems impossible to bind a shortcut to a single key like "T", am I right ?

Comment: Correct. Otherwise how would you type a "t" character?

Comment: @bjbk Sure, if the shortcut were to work also when prompting text, that would be problematic. But when not in a prompting text environement, I don't see what would go wrong ?

Comment: Do you use single keys in other software?  I know that in Presenter Mode, single keys are mapped for actions.  i.e.: "B" for blackout or "[" for next slide without animation.  But I have not seen this done while editing documents.  Modifier keys are used throughout the OS (even Windows uses them).  In fact, to type a capital letter, the Shift modifier key is always used.  So adding modifiers can be intuitive and useful.

Comment: @bjbk VI for instance ? Also, inkscape for instance has single key shortcuts, emacs allows for modifier + letter + letter, which enhances considerably the number of possibilities, while not requiring to hit more than two keys at the same time (because, really, cmd+shift+opt+fn+W, how many fingers does ont need for this ?). Thanks for your answer below, I wish I could upvote.

Comment: I agree.  Certainly would expand the use of the keyboard.  Thanks for your comment and the food for thought! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

OS X does not allow mapping of single characters as Menu Shortcuts.  Apple has specific [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/Keyboard.html) on the use of Keyboard shortcuts.  Although this document is for designing software meant to be used in the OS X environment, the principles they use may assist in understanding their reasoning.

At least one **Modifier** key must be used when generating shortcuts.

- <kbd>⌃</kbd> Control
- <kbd>⌥</kbd> Option
- <kbd>⇧</kbd> Shift (used only in conjunction with one of the other 3)
- <kbd>⌘</kbd> Command ←  Preferred modifier